# Understanding property based testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

I'm reading about property based testing and I'm wondering how can I test this my code using that paradigm.

```
class Invoice {

    private final String id;
    private final String companyName;

    public String name() {
        return id + "_" + removeDots(companyName.trim());
    }

}
```

I want to test `Invoice::name` method, so I would do something like this:

```
class InvoiceTest {

    //Let's say 'id' and 'companyName' are random auto-generated values
    //by some framework
    @Test 
    public void nameTest(String id, String companyName) {
        Invoice invoice = new Invoice(id, companyName);
        assertThat(invoice.name()).isEqualTo(id + "_" + removeDots(companyName.trim()));
    }

}
```

As you see, it makes no sense. I'm reimplementing the logic in the test method. Maybe, is property based testing suitable only for "mathematical" logic?

Comment: "Property-based testing" in the context you've illustrated in your question is no different from method or function testing.  The same rules and regulations apply.

Comment: So, are just "mathematical" or arithmetic contexts where PBT should be applied?

Comment: Have a look at the illustration provided [here](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/property_based_testing).  *"A property is a high-level specification of behavior that should hold for a range of data points. For example, a property might state that the size of a list returned from a method should always be greater than or equal to the size of the list passed to that method."*

Comment: *"The difference between a traditional test and a property is that tests traditionally verify behavior based on specific data points checked by the test. A test might pass three or four specific lists of different sizes to a method under test that takes a list, for example, and check the results are as expected. A property, by contrast, would describe at a high level the preconditions of the method under test and specify some aspect of the result that should hold no matter what valid list is passed."*

Comment: Understood. So property based testing is to verify domain invariants. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

> Maybe, is property based testing suitable only for "mathematical" logic?

Not necessarily.

> Writing tests first forces you to think about the problem you're solving. Writing property-based tests forces you to think way harder. -- [Jessica Kerr](https://twitter.com/jessitron/status/327480330900611072?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)

```
boolean hasDots(String candidate) { ... }

@Test
public void it_removes_the_dots(String anyCompanyName) {
    String id = "0";
    Invoice invoice = new Invoice(id, anyCompanyName);
    String name = invoice.name();

    assertFalse( hasDots(name) );
}

@Test
public void it_leaves_the_same_when_no_dots(String anyCompanyNameWithoutDots) {
    assume ! hasDots(anyCompanyNameWithoutDots);

    String id = "0";
    Invoice invoice = new Invoice(id, anyCompanyNameWithoutDots);
    String invoiceName = invoice.name()

    assertTrue(invoiceName.endsWith(anyCompanyNameWithoutDots));
}

@Test
public void it_prepends_the_identifier_without_changing_it(String anyIdentifier) {
    String companyName = "BobsBoringBusiness";
    Invoice invoice = new Invoice(anyIdentifier, companyName );
    String invoiceName = invoice.name()

    assertTrue(invoiceName.startsWith(anyIdentifier));
}


@Test
public void it_prepends_the_identifier_without_removing_dots(String anyIdentifierWithDots) {
    assume hasDots(anyIdentifierWithDots);

    String companyName = "BobsBoringBusiness";
    Invoice invoice = new Invoice(anyIdentifierWithDots, companyName );
    String invoiceName = invoice.name()

    assertTrue(invoiceName.startsWith(anyIdentifierWithDots));
}
// ... and so on.
```